# How to retrieve data from DB without rerunning the server? (Django)

Tags: django

so I have multiple apps for my website; one to register, one to view a map with the users locations plotted on, and one to view the users' profiles. But those three apps need access to the same model, namely: User. (On the register page it gets created and added to DB, the map page needs its hometown in order to locate it on the map, and the profile pages also need it obviously). But whenever I add a new user on the admin page, I first have to rerun the server in order for it to appear on the map. Beforehand when the model was defined in just one app, I just needed to refresh the page to see the change. I have created the User model in the Register app and redirected to it in other apps like this:

```
class Meta(models.Model):
db_table = 'register_User'
```

Why doesnt the template retrieve the up to date data without restarting the server?

I hope u can help out

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the Django ORM is not correct.
You should not use the Meta in a models.Model class to reference a table in order to be able to access it.
If you need a model from a different app, just import it like this:

```
from user.models import User
```

And then you can use it in your views or models.
For a better understanding on how the Django ORM works, i recommend the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) or the [models.Model reference pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/).

Comment: I have deleted the meta in both other apps model class, but somehow the marker (in Google Maps) that was assigned to the user still appears whenever I delete that particular user